# boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.request_spot_instances() does not return boto.ec2.spotinstancerequest.SpotInstanceRequest

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

The title says the problem.

I'm requesting a spot instance with boto like so (aws key and secret key are environment vars set in ~/.boto):

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_ec2()
type(conn)
> boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection

response = conn.request_spot_instances(**params)
type(response)
> boto.resultset.ResultSet
```

params has values for price, image_id, instance_type, and placement.

This is where the library deviates from its documentation. As you can see in the [boto docs](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html), request_spot_instances() is supposed to return `boto.ec2.spotinstancerequest.SpotInstanceRequest`, but it returns `boto.resultset.ResultSet`.

There are no methods to get the request id for `boto.resultset.ResultSet`, which is what I'm really after. I dont want to parse the value that's returned from printing `response`, but I can't find a gooed way to get to it in the docs.

```
print(response)
> [SpotInstanceRequest:sir-xxxxxxx]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is not an issue anymore

```
In [120]: type(response[0])
Out[120]: boto.ec2.spotinstancerequest.SpotInstanceRequest
```

You just had to reference the first object of the list. Still, I feel like the docs should be updated to reflect that the function returns a list containing `SpotInstanceRequest`